# Looping over a set of number generating commands in R

Tags: r, loops, random, tidyverse, simulation

Below, I'm showing a block of code to generate some set of item scores in `R`. However, there seems to be a fair amount of unnecessary repetition to get to the final `data`.

I was wondering if there might be a more compact way of achieving the same `data` in `R`?

```
set.seed(8649)     
N      = 10        
latent = rnorm(N)  

##### generate latent responses to items
item1 = latent + rnorm(N, mean=0, sd=0.2)  
item2 = latent + rnorm(N, mean=0, sd=0.3)
item3 = latent + rnorm(N, mean=0, sd=0.5)
item4 = latent + rnorm(N, mean=0, sd=1.0)
item5 = latent + rnorm(N, mean=0, sd=1.2)  

##### convert latent responses to ordered categories
item1 = findInterval(item1, vec=c(-Inf,-2.5,-1, 1,2.5,Inf)) 
item2 = findInterval(item2, vec=c(-Inf,-2.5,-1, 1,2.5,Inf))
item3 = findInterval(item3, vec=c(-Inf,-3,  -2, 2,3,  Inf))  
item4 = findInterval(item4, vec=c(-Inf,-3,  -2, 2,3,  Inf))
item5 = findInterval(item5, vec=c(-Inf,-3.5,-3,-1,0.5,Inf))

data = cbind(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5)
```

Comment: I guess you may create a function as some arguments are changing

Comment: Based on the way you are creating the output, it can be a list.  I posted a solution.  may be that helps you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create the first sets of 'item' in a `list` with the variable part as 'sd'

```
# // loop over the sd vector and create the list of random numbers in a list
lst1 <- lapply(c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 1, 1.2), function(x) 
           latent + rnorm(N, mean = 0, sd = x))
# // set the names of the list if needed
names(lst1) <- paste0("item", seq_along(lst1))
```

Use `Map` to loop over the corresponding elements of 'lst1' and the `vec` as a `list` ('veclst') and apply the `findInterval`

```
data.frame(Map(findInterval, lst1, vec = veclst))
#   item1 item2 item3 item4 item5
#1      4     4     3     3     5
#2      3     3     3     3     5
#3      3     3     3     3     5
#4      4     4     4     3     5
#5      2     2     3     2     4
#6      3     3     3     3     3
#7      3     3     3     3     4
#8      2     2     2     2     2
#9      4     4     5     4     5
#10     3     3     3     3     4
```

---

Or the same done with `tidyverse`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
map2_dfc(c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 1, 1.2), veclst, ~ 
          findInterval(latent + rnorm(N, mean = 0, sd = .x), vec = .y)) %>%
  set_names(str_c('item', seq_along(.)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 5
#  item1 item2 item3 item4 item5
#   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1     4     4     3     4     4
# 2     3     3     3     3     5
# 3     3     3     3     3     4
# 4     3     4     3     3     5
# 5     2     2     3     3     4
# 6     3     3     3     3     5
# 7     3     3     3     3     4
# 8     2     2     2     1     2
# 9     4     4     4     5     5
#10     3     3     3     3     4
```

#### Update

If we are creating a function, make sure the `latent` is created based on the new 'N' passed within the function as it can lead to a difference in length.  In the original code showed in OP' post, the `length` is 10 and `latent` was created based on that

```
make_likert <- function(N.judge = 10, item.sds, cut_points, seed = NULL){
   set.seed(seed)
   latent <- rnorm(N.judge)
   lst1 <- lapply(item.sds, function(x) latent + rnorm(n = N.judge, sd = x))
      names(lst1) <- paste0("item", seq_along(lst1))
      data.frame(Map(findInterval, lst1, cut_points))
     }
      
make_likert(N.judge=13, item.sds = item.sds, cut_points = cut_points)
#     item1 item2 item3 item4 item5 item6 item7 item8 item9 item10
#1      4     3     2     3     1     3     3     5     4      4
#2      5     3     3     3     5     3     3     5     5      5
#3      2     2     3     3     3     3     3     4     3      5
#4      3     5     3     3     3     3     4     5     4      3
#5      3     1     4     3     4     3     1     2     4      4
#6      2     1     3     3     1     3     3     5     5      4
#7      3     2     3     3     3     3     5     1     5      3
#8      3     1     2     3     5     3     3     5     3      5
#9      4     3     2     3     3     4     3     1     5      5
#10     3     2     3     3     1     3     4     3     3      2
#11     4     5     1     3     5     3     1     3     5      5
#12     3     5     3     3     3     3     5     3     5      5
#13     3     4     5     3     3     3     1     1     5      3
```

#### data

```
veclst <- rep(list(c(-Inf,-2.5,-1, 1,2.5,Inf), 
                   c(-Inf,-3,  -2, 2,3,  Inf),
                   c(-Inf,-3.5,-3,-1,0.5,Inf)), 
           c(2, 2, 1))
```

Comment: @rnorouzian updated with tidyverse.  With piping, it can be made more flexible

Comment: @rnorouzian it is similar to `cut` in creating buckets or finding the interval.  With `cut`, you can get a factor with labels, but findInterval, returns an index value.  According to `?findInterval`, the algorithm does `for each index j in x v[i[j]] ≤ x[j] < v[i[j] + 1] where v[0] := - Inf, v[N+1] := + Inf,`

Comment: @rnorouzian Yes, it can be used as well.  I think `findInterval` would be faster because it doesn't have to do with attributes

Comment: @rnorouzian No, here, `N` is a constant used in all the elements

Comment: @rnorouzian Here, the `latent` should be inside the function as it is based on a length of 10

Comment: @rnorouzian yes, but you have defined `latent <- rnorm(N)` where `N` is defined as 10.  in your code.  NOw, withtin the function if you pass `N.judge = 13`, there is a length difference in 10 and 13 when you do `latent + `

Comment: Arun, do you know why I'm getting error when using `make_likert()` with the following arguments: `cut_points <- rep(list(c(-Inf,0,Inf), 
                       c(-Inf,0,  Inf),
                       c(-Inf,0,Inf)), 
                  c(2, 2, 2));

item.sds <- c(0.5, .75, .5, 1, 1.2, .4)`

Comment: @rnorouzian it is working fine for me with `make_likert(N.judge=13, item.sds = item.sds, cut_points = cut_points)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mapply`. E.g. like this:

```r
mapply(findInterval, vec = v_arg,
       x = lapply(sig_arg, rnorm, mean = latent, n = N)) 
#R>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#R>  [1,]    4    4    3    3    3
#R>  [2,]    3    3    3    4    5
#R>  [3,]    3    3    3    4    4
#R>  [4,]    4    4    3    3    5
#R>  [5,]    2    2    3    3    3
#R>  [6,]    3    3    3    3    5
#R>  [7,]    3    3    3    3    4
#R>  [8,]    1    1    2    3    3
#R>  [9,]    4    4    3    3    5
#R> [10,]    3    3    3    3    4
```

If you want the column names, then use e.g.:

```r
mapply(findInterval,
       setNames(lapply(sig_arg, rnorm, mean = latent, n = N), 
                paste0("item", seq_along(sig_arg))), 
       v_arg)
#R>       item1 item2 item3 item4 item5
#R>  [1,]     4     4     3     3     3
#R>  [2,]     3     3     3     4     5
#R>  [3,]     3     3     3     4     4
#R>  [4,]     4     4     3     3     5
#R>  [5,]     2     2     3     3     3
#R>  [6,]     3     3     3     3     5
#R>  [7,]     3     3     3     3     4
#R>  [8,]     1     1     2     3     3
#R>  [9,]     4     4     3     3     5
#R> [10,]     3     3     3     3     4
```

You can wrap this into a functions such that you can change `N`, the standard deviations, and the break points like this:

```r
sim_scores <- function(N, sigs, cuts)
  mapply(findInterval,
         setNames(lapply(sigs, rnorm, mean = rnorm(N), n = N), 
                  paste0("item", seq_along(cuts))), 
         cuts)

# use the function
sim_scores(10L, sig_arg, v_arg)
#R>       item1 item2 item3 item4 item5
#R>  [1,]     3     3     3     2     3
#R>  [2,]     3     3     3     3     5
#R>  [3,]     3     3     3     3     4
#R>  [4,]     5     4     4     4     5
#R>  [5,]     3     3     3     3     3
#R>  [6,]     3     3     3     3     5
#R>  [7,]     3     4     3     3     5
#R>  [8,]     2     2     3     3     3
#R>  [9,]     3     3     3     3     4
#R> [10,]     2     2     3     3     2

sim_scores(4L, sig_arg[1:2], v_arg[1:2])
#R>      item1 item2
#R> [1,]     2     2
#R> [2,]     3     3
#R> [3,]     2     3
#R> [4,]     3     3
```

#### Data

```r
sig_arg <- c(.2, .3, .5, 1, 1.5)
v_arg <- list(c(-Inf,-2.5,-1, 1,2.5,Inf), 
              c(-Inf,-2.5,-1, 1,2.5,Inf), 
              c(-Inf,-3,  -2, 2,3,  Inf), 
              c(-Inf,-3,  -2, 2,3,  Inf), 
              c(-Inf,-3.5,-3,-1,0.5,Inf))
```